# fixed UI element in Aframe

Tags: aframe

Is it possible to set fixed position for UI elements in an Aframe. When the user navigates in the environment, the element remains fixed in the same place?
For Example, I want to set fixed position for this element

`<a-entity text="value: Hello World;"></a-entity>`

Comment: When you said "fixed in the same place", do you mean fixed on the screen no matter where user look? If that is the case, you might consider placing a plain HTML element outside aframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your entities children of the camera:

`<a-camera><a-entity text="value: Hello World;" position="0 0 1"></a-entity></a-camera>`

[Example to illustrate](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/intermediate-trader?path=index.html:11:6)